# OpenCV mean function crashes with mask created from OpenCV threshold function?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix, threshold

I'm very new to OpenCV, so I guess I'm making some silly mistake.

First I'm creating an empty `cv::mat` matrix, `mask`, of `CV_8U` type and filling it with zeros. Then I'm filling the matrix with either 0's or 255's by checking the values in `CV_32FC1` type `cv::mat` matrix `croppedDifferenceImage` by the use of `cv::threshold`. Then I'm using `mask` as a parameter for `cv::mean` function.

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat(croppedDifferenceImage.rows, croppedDifferenceImage.cols, CV_8U, cv::Scalar(0));
cv::threshold(croppedDifferenceImage, mask, 3.2, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
double mean = cv::mean(croppedDifferenceImage, mask)[0];
```

But I keep having a crash with the message:

```
/build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/stat.cpp:565: error: (-215) mask.empty() || mask.type() == CV_8U in function mean
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason you are using opencv 2.4.0 and not opencv 3?

Comment: I don't know if there is any reason. I've just joined this project and very new to opencv too.

Comment: What is the type of `mask`? According to documentation for `threshold`, the destination is of "the same size and type as src". That means that you're passing a CV_32FC1 as a mask to `mean`, which is not valid.

Comment: is `croppedDifferenceImage` a color image or a grey scale image?

Comment: @mask "values in CV_32FC1 type cv::mat matrix croppedDifferenceImage" -- Single channel. Also notice that the assert doesn't mention anything about the depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`cv::threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold):

> ```
> double threshold(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, double thresh, double maxval, int type)
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> - src – input array (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit floating point).
> - dst – output array of the same size and type as src.

Therefore, since you say that `croppedDifferenceImage` is of type `CV_32FC1`, the `mask` output variable will be reallocated and become type `CV_32FC1` as well (irrespective of you initializing it before, since it was an incorrect type).

Next you pass this mask to `cv::mean`, which (according to the assert) requires the mask:

- Not to be empty
- To be of type CV_8U (that particular check does not concern itself with the number of channels).

So, in order to solve this problem, you need to convert (using [`Mat::convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto)) the mask after thresholding:

```
cv::threshold(croppedDifferenceImage, mask, 3.2, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
mask.convertTo(mask, CV_8U)
double mean = cv::mean(croppedDifferenceImage, mask)[0];
```

---

Also see [Miki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36556804/3962537) for suggestion about using only logical operations on `cv::Mat` instead of call to `cv::threshold`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Dan Mašek in the comments, the result of `threshold` will have the same type as the input. So in your case, since you're passing a `CV_32FC1` matrix, the type of `mask` will be `CV_32FC1`, which is not what `mean` expects.

Basically, you need to be sure to pass to `mean` a mask of type `CV_8UC1`.

Instead of converting the `mask` to the correct type, since you're using a simple threshold, you can use `Mat` logical operations, that will give you always a `CV_8UC1` result:

```
Mat mask = croppedDifferenceImage > 3.2;
double mean = cv::mean(croppedDifferenceImage, mask)[0];
```

Otherwise, you can convert the `mask` to the correct type:

```
Mat mask;
threshold(croppedDifferenceImage, mask, 3.2, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
mask.convertTo(mask, CV_8U);

double mean = cv::mean(croppedDifferenceImage, mask)[0];
```

---

Remember also that you don't need to pre-allocate the result of OpenCV operations (i.e. `OutputArray`).